# meta-schema features in VS Code extension warning in version ^1.68.0

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, openapi

So basically I have a VS Code extension that provides JSON file validation **based on the built in JSON validator**. The schema that I'm validating against (OpenAPI 3.1.x) uses meta-schema features, i.e. `$dynamicRef`, which I also need to use, since I reference the OpenAPI schema.

When defining a custom schema like the following, I get a warning stating that the validator doesn't support meta-schema features yet. Needless to say, validation does really not work. When using normal `$ref`, most of the schema work but not properties that use `$dynamicRef`. So I'm forced to reference the schema by `$dynamicRef` as well.

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "$id": "OpenApiPathObject",
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": {
    "$dynamicRef": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/main/schemas/v3.1/schema.json#/$defs/path-item-or-reference"
  }
}
```

```
The schema uses meta-schema features ($dynamicRef) that are not yet supported by the validator.
```

I'm using VS Code 1.69.0 and changed the required engine of my extension to ^1.68.0, which should include support for schema verion `Draft 2020-12` as stated in the [May 2022 release notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_68#_expanded-json-schema-support). What are my options here and how can I come around this warning?

Here's an excerpt of the extension `package.json`

```json
...
"engines": {
    "vscode": "^1.68.0"
},
...
```

Comment: Update: The feature is not yet implemented in the underlying json-service. I have opened an issued on GitHub. If you, like me, want this feature to be added, be sure to leave your thumb up. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/155379

Comment: is this now fix? encountering the same warning

Comment: Unfortunately not yet. It's been added to the backlog AFAIK.